# Find values greater than or equal to 0.021 to 0 using awk

Tags: awk

I have a large file with three sections. Part of it only has 3 columns, then it moves to the image section and it has 5 columns, then the rotation section which has 7 columns (I'm interested in changing the rotation section only).
I'm trying to get `awk` to produce a file that changes all negative values to `0` and all positive numbers greater than `0.2` to `0`.
The values that I'm concerned with are only in column 7 and must be in the line containing the word `ROTATION`.

Here is my attempt.

```
awk BEGIN '/ROTATION/ {if (function abs($7) > = 0.021) $7=0; print}' awktest.tlt > awktest1.tlt
```

I need awk to keep the rest of the data in there as well and not just produce the change from X to 0.

As far as executing it I am using `awk -f fix.awk awktest.tlt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
awk 'NF==7&&/ROTATION/{if($7<0||$7>0.2)$7=0}1' file
```

Comment: For some reason I am receiving syntax errors on the apostrophe, why is that?

awk 'NF==$7&&/ROTATION/&&$7<0||$7>0.2{$7=0}1' awktest.tlt > awktest2.tlt
    ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: And is there a different version, more so like mine, that could produce the same result as what you posted? Thank you :). I'm VERY new to this and I'm trying to learn...had to start today!

Comment: You shouldn't see any errors with either. Scirpts have been tested.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will have to ask my prof. tomorrow. Must be an issue with the computer itself.